# How to share a Google Calendar with a Google Plus circle?

Tags: google-plus, google-calendar

Currently I can share a Google Calendar with individuals using their email addresses, but I can't just share it with a pre-defined Google+ Circle. How can I do this?

(This is for personal use only, so I don't want a business solution. I do not have a Google Apps account.)

Comment: Did you considered to make the calendar public and shared it with the circle?

Comment: it's a private calendar

Comment: To share a private calendar, and keep it private, the calendar manager should know the email address of the people to share it with.

Comment: @Rubén i already know that and have stated that in question already..

Comment: I added an extended version of my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Google Calendar only offer two ways to share a private calendar with other users

1. By adding their individual email addresses
2. By adding the email address of a group from Google Groups

## Explanation

Google+ Classic events are integrated with Google Calendar but Calendars on Google Calendar are not.

It's worth to say that people could use Google+ Classic profile or Google About Me settings to share their email addresses with Public, Circles or custom circles.

If people on the circle to share the calendar with doesn't share their email address with the calendar manager and they are not member of a group on Google Groups, then the private calendar can't be shared with them.

## References

- [Share your calendar with someone - Google Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en)